# css dropdown menu acting weird

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu (available at gosu.pl/menu, dropdown menu 1, example 1)

but I'm strangely I'm having different effects in different browsers, and not in the usual IE buggering everything up type of way.

I'm on my localhost and using cakephp (although that shouldn't make a difference). When I view through FF the menu looks ok and the dropdown bit appears where it's supposed to [see](http://cybernos-ac.co.uk/Untitled-2.jpg)

but if I press ctrl+f5 to empty cache and refresh the page it turns into [this](http://cybernos-ac.co.uk/Untitled-3.jpg)

The weird thing is if I hit just f5 to reload the page, it goes back to normal, then ctrl+f5 back to wonkey again.

I've tested in in IE and all versions seem ok even when I reload. Safari and chrome are both wonkey no matter what but opera is fine.

I've compared the html and the css when both wonkey and normal are displayed and everything is exactly the same.  Can anyone enlighten me what the problem is? I guess something to do with cache but why would it be different in the different browsers?

I'm sorry I can't post html or css coz I'm on my local machine.

Help!

Comment: try an example at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: +1 for using the word _wonkey_ in a post, but -1 for not posting any code.

Comment: sorry for the crap way of posting this but here's the html, http://cybernos-ac.co.uk/one.txt      and heres the css  http://cybernos-ac.co.uk/onecss.txt

Comment: at what point, this question starts to be about cakephp?

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally not a big fan of using tables as menu items. Better practice is to use lists with list-items.

```
div#mainmenu_bottom ul {    
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;    
}

div#mainmenu_bottom ul li {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    height:25px;
}

div#mainmenu_bottom ul li ul {
    display:none;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    -moz-opacity:0.9;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 1px;
}

div#mainmenu_bottom ul li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:236px;  
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px -5px;    
    width:150px;
    display:block;      
    border:1px solid #00451A;

}

div#mainmenu_bottom ul li li {
    width:140px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #00451A;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    background-color:#00451A;   
    margin:0px;
    height:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

div#mainmenu_bottom ul li li:hover {
    background-position:-50px -4px;
    background-image:url('../images/interface/bg_block_groot.jpg');
}
```

Structure would be like this

```
<div id="mainmenu_bottom">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="mainmenu">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="mainmenu">Test 2</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>link 1</li>     
                <li>link 2</li> 
                <li>link 3</li> 
            </ul>
            <a href="" class="mainmenu">Test 3</a>
        </li>            
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just going by what that tutorial I was following said to do. Is the fact that it's in a table what's causing the problems? thanks for posting by the way

Comment: Using tables for everything is bad practice. Tables are designed for displaying data. Using above code should provide you with a cross-browser compatible dropdown-menu.